# How to apply Filter for the below JSON Array in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I have a JSON array in the following structure**

```
translations ={
      "English" :[  
                {"Localizedtext":"Submit",
                 "TextCode":1},
                {"LocalizedText":"blah"
                 "TextCode":2 },
             {-------900 odd objects }]
     "SelectedLanguage": [
               "1":{"Localizedtext":"Submit",
                    "TextCode":1,
                    "TextID" :100},
               "2":{"Localizedtext":"development",
                    "TextCode":1,
                    "TextID" :101},
                "1008" :{"Localizedtext":"blah",
                         "TextCode":1,
                         "TextID" :102},
               "80,000":{"Localizedtext":"foo",
                         "TextCode":1,
                         "TextID" :103},
                 {-------900 odd objects }]
              }
```

**My HTML page looks like this :**

```
<tr ng-repeat="Translation in translations.english|searchFilter : search">
       <td>{{Translation.TextCode}}</td>
      <td>{{Translation.LocalizedText }}
<div><textarea ng-model="translations.selectedLangauge[Translation.TextCode].LocalizedText" ng-change="getTranslations(Translation.TextCode)" class="text-area" rows="2">{{ translations.selectedLangauge[Translation.TextCode].LocalizedText }}
</textarea>
</div>
</td>
```

**My custom filter which i have designed looks like this :**

```
     .filter('searchFilter', function () {
        return function (items, search) {
            if (!search){
                return items;
            }
            var result = [];
            angular.forEach(items, function (value, key) {
                //console.log(items);

                angular.forEach(value, function (value2,key2) {
                    //console.log(value2);
                        if (search===value2) {
                            result.push(value2);
                        }



                });

            });
            return result;


        }
    });
```

**The filter that i have designed is applicalble only to translations.english array of the translation object .How to apply this to both the arrays of the object?**

Answer (score 0):

You have to concat the arrays before iterating over them. Filter will be applied on the joined arrays.

```
ng-repeat="Translation in 
    translations.english.concat( translations.SelectedLanguage )|searchFilter : search"
```

Comment: If i concatenate the array then how to populate the selected languages in the text area of the HTML page ,because the objects(key names) in both the arrays are same .